# Capybara/selenium: wait for element to become hidden

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I need to wait for loading bar (div#loading) to disappear (become display: none) in a cucumber step. I'd expect the following to do the trick

```
find('#loading').should_not be_visible
```

But it doesn't seem to be waiting. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to use the `wait_until` to wait for your condition to be met.

```
wait_until { !page.evaluate_script(%{$('#loading').is(':visible')}) }
```

*There might be a better wait to check for visibility, but last time I checked `page.has_no_css` does not work with things like `:visible`.*

(***Update***) Though `has_css` does not see selectors like `:visible`, `Capybara::Node::Element` does have some methods to make the above a bit prettier.

```
wait_until { !find("#loading").visible? }
```

Comment: @MikeAski might be useful to add the new proposed way for those coming here in the future. God I hate cucumber